# Создание собственного списка c++

Tags: c++, списки

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь воспроизвести похожее на `list` из библиотеки `stl`.

У меня имеется класс `ListADT`, у которого три метода `конструктор`, `метод вставки элемента` и `деструктор`.

```
#pragma once
const int defMaxListSize = 10;
typedef char DataType;

class ListADT
{
private:
    //Data members
    int maxSize;
    int size;
    int cursor;

    DataType *dataItems;
public:
    //Constructor
    ListADT(int maxNumber=defMaxListSize)throw(bad_alloc);

    //Destructor
    ~ListADT();

    //List manipulation operations
    void insert(const DataType &newDataItem)    //Insert after cursor
        throw(logic_error);

};
```

**Конструктор** - создает пустой список. Выделяет достаточно памяти для списка, содержащего количество элементов данных числом `maxNumber`.

**Insert**-вставляет элемент в конец списка, но перед эти проверяет "пуст ли список или нет?"

**Деструктор** - Освобождает память, используемую для хранения списка.

Для реализации я столкнулся с таким казусом,а именно, как правильно использовать `исключение` для таких методов. И после этого остановился на реализации этих трех методов.
Не могли бы вы подсказать, как правильно обращаться с `throw` при создании такой структуры?

Надеюсь на помощь,спасибо!

Comment: Вообще-то, судя по всему, вы создаете вектор. А во-вторых, в чем суть вопроса - честно говоря, не очень понятно...

Comment: @Harry  не могу понять, как использовать исключения при создание методов. Ведь принцип , я думаю, создания меняется,например, для выделения памяти.
Не могли вы мне показать пример создания конструктора , а на основе вашего примера, я бы постарался идти дальше сам.

Comment: Ну на сколько я понимаю list у вас будет двусвязный список, а исключение bad_alloc он автоматически может кинуть если возникла проблема с выделением памяти на куче...

Comment: Для чего вы хотите их использовать? Какие такие могут быть исключительные ситуации? Разве что `new`, но он и сам его сгенерирует, если что. А указывать спецификацию исключений уже давно не рекомендуется - разве только `nothrow`, если их не может быть.

Comment: @Harry т.е.я могу убрать все `throw` , потому что получится,что все исключения которые могут произойти, они автоматически сгенерируются компилятором?Но ведь ,даже если так, можете показать реализацию с `throw`  для new такой структуры? если вам не трудно.

Comment: Ну, разве что так: `if ((dataItems = new (std::nothrow) DataType[size]) == nullptr) throw bad_alloc();` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно гуглить безопасность исключений (exception safely). Советую почитать Майерса, в первую очередь, "Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных советов...". Прочитать Modern C++ также полезно, но только после прочтения предыдущей.

Если в кратце: декларация `throw(bad_alloc)` является устаревшей в С++11 и C++14. Если функция не бросает исключений, используйте noexcept, или throw(), если это C++98. Если бросает, просто документируйте. Реально полезной может быть информация о том, что функция никогда  не бросает исключений, тогда компилятор может применить лучшие оптимизации.

Список (хотя в вашем случае это вектор, стоит использовать устоявшееся в экосистеме C++ название) может выбрасывать исключения как минимум в случае добавления новых элементов. При этом исключение может возникнуть из-за нехватки памяти, или его может бросить конструктор создаваемого в списке элемента. В обоих случаях вы должны просто игнорировать его, пропуская наружу, но нужно следить, что бы не произошло утечек ресурсов и ваш список находился в допустимом состоянии. Для этого желательно использовать умные указатели, std::unique_ptr, например. Кроме того, исключение может возникнуть при копировании/перемещении элементов, и их тоже нужно пропускать наружу, но при этом нужно не допускать некорректного состояния списка. Майерс достаточно подробно эту тему освещает.

А вот деструктор, по хорошему, вам вообще писать не надо, он должен генерироваться автоматически при использовании умных указателей. Но если вы реализуете действительно список, а не массив, деструктор нужен, т.к. автоматически сгенерированный деструктор будет рекурсивным, его нужно развернуть в цикл.

Comment: Спасибо, понял вас, буду разбираться!